# サーバー上でIllustratoのaiファイルを加工

Tags: バイナリファイル

Illustratorのaiファイルをサーバー上で加工する方法を探しています
言語、OSは問いません。

具体的には以下のような感じの事を行いたいと思っています
１．Illustratorを使ってaiファイルを作成。その際にアウトライン化せずにテキストを埋め込む
２．１のファイルをサーバー上に置く
３．１のファイルのテキスト部分をプログラムを介して動的に変更して保存する

もし何かわかる方がおりましたら、ご教授お願いできますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もしかしたら、[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/26370)かも？

「Illustratorのaiファイルをサーバー上で加工」することが最終目的ではなくて、「何か」の「作業手順」の「一部分」として上記作業を行いたいのでは？
そして、**処理結果を Illustrator に戻さなくても良くて、やりたいこと・表現したいことが機能範囲に収まっているならば、他の製品でも良いと考えられる場合**、同じ Adobe 製品の中で [InDesign Server](https://www.adobe.com/jp/products/indesignserver.html) というものがあります。これはサーバーにインストールしてドキュメントの自動生成が出来るものです。

> 自動化されたプロセスでプロフェッショナルなデザインをカスタマイズした自動化機能をInDesignに組み合わせた高度なツール InDesign Server
>   Adobe® InDesign® Serverは、InDesignのデザイン、レイアウト、タイポグラフィ機能を活用し、魅力的なドキュメントをプログラムによって自動生成できるようにする、堅牢かつスケーラブルなエンジンです。デスクトップ製品と同じコアエンジンを使用しています。デスクトップ用に作成されたプラグインやスクリプトは、InDesign Serverでも実行できます。InDesign Serverは開発者向け製品であり、多くの場合、コンテンツ管理ソリューション、ワークフローソリューション、印刷用ソリューションなどの様々な パートナーソリューションに組み込まれています。InDesign Serverでプログラミングをおこない、適切にデザインされ、レイアウトが固定された広告やコンテンツ要素などのデジタル出力を作成することもできます。

[入門ガイド：基本的な考え方](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/indesign/how-to/introduction-guide-basic.html)
[ADOBE INDESIGN CC SERVER よくある質問](https://www.adobe.com/jp/products/indesignserver/faq.html)

Illustlatorのファイルそのままでは無いですが、データは形式そのままで取り込みは出来るようです。
[他のアプリケーションからのファイルの読み込み](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/indesign/using/importing-files-applications.html)

自動化はこの辺の機能で出来るのでしょう。
[XML、IDML およびスクリプティングを利用した自動パブリッシング](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/indesign/automation.html)

> InDesign ワークフローの自動化をお考えの方は、InDesign がさらに強力、柔軟、かつスケーラブルになった Adobe InDesign Server についてもご覧ください。InDesign Server は、InDesign と同じコードベースを使用しているので、デスクトップバージョンの全機能に加え、サーバーベースの機能も多数備えています。

[InDesign でのスクリプト](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/indesign/using/scripting.html)

ただし、処理結果を Illustrator で再度編集できるものにする完全互換は難しいようです。
[InDesignのデータをIllustratorデータに、可能な限り変換する](http://watanabedesign511.info/2015/03/10/indd-to-ai/)

> リスク
>
> - フォントをアウトライン化するので、Illustrator上で文字の修正は出来ない。アウトラインを取らなくてもPDF化は出来ますが、文字組が崩れる危険があるのと、Illustratorで開いた時に、一文字ずつパスが分割されてしまいました。
> - アウトラインを取ると、段落境界線など、InDesign独自の便利な機能が消える。一応、文字ツールでテキストをラインで選択すると、境界線を活かしたままアウトラインが取れますが、文字間が詰まるなど、組が崩れる危険があります。
> - 画像を手作業でリンクし直さないといけない。埋め込みでそのまま入稿出来る場合は大丈夫ですが、再リンクする場合は、ファイル名も埋め込みによって消えてしまっているので注意が必要です。
> - 透明効果がラスタライズされる。InDesignで使用したドロップシャドウや透明の効果はラスタライズされた状態になるので再度編集するのは厳しいです。
> - InDesignのグラデーションで作成したオブジェクトが、Illustratorで開いたら消えていた、など、予期せぬエラーが起きたこともありました。
>
> このように、出来上がったIllustratorデータは殆ど再編集が出来ないものとなります。

他参考記事
[InDesign CC自動化作戦](http://www.openspc2.org/book/InDesignCC/)
[デザイン自動化（InDesign基本編）](https://qiita.com/esflat/items/07beb6c0855b6b76d459)
[InDesignの自動化に役立つ知識とツールのまとめ](https://qiita.com/y_hokkey/items/7e883843873968721942)

Comment: 素晴らしい回答ありがとうございました！  
今回の投稿はまさしくXY問題であり、印刷用の大量データを自動で生成するプログラムを開発するための、一部の機能の事について知見を求めておりました。  
aiファイルにのみ焦点を当てていたので、kunifさんのアドバイスが無ければInDesign Server の存在知ることはなかったと思います、  
大変貴重で有用なご意見ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office 等と同様 Adobe Illustrator をサーバー上で非対話的に使うのはライセンス違反のようです。あなたが自分で作ったプログラムが ai ファイルを自動生成する分には違反になりません。 ai ファイルのファイルフォーマットは公開されていますので、入手の上 [c](/questions/tagged/c) でも [php](/questions/tagged/php) でも使って好きに生成すればよいでしょう。 ai ファイル仕様書を入手するには Adobe と契約が必要そうですが詳細まで調べていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！  Adobeにファイルフォーマットについて問い合わせてみます。